# Why does these rules work? (finding last element in list in prolog)

Tags: prolog

I am trying to understand the following set of rules, which supposed to find the last element in a list (for instance `my_list(X,[1,2,3])` gives `X=3`).

```
my_last(X,[X]).
my_last(X, [_|L]) :- my_last(X, L).
```

I understand the first fact - X is the last element of a list if X is the only element in it, but how does the second rule work? this looks a bit strange to me as a prolog noob, I'd love to know if there's an intutive way to interprate it.
T

Comment: what is L with regards to [ _ | L ]?

Answer (score 2):

Read the Prolog predicate as logical rules. If there is more than one predicate clause for the predicate, you can think of it as "OR":

```
my_last(X,[X]).
```

> `X` is the last element of the list, `[X]`.

```
my_last(X, [_|L]) :- my_last(X, L).
```

> `X` is the last element of the list `[_|L]` *if* `X` is the last element of the list `L`.

The second clause is a *recursive* definition. So it does, ultimately, need to terminate with the recursive call not matching the head of the recursive clause that is calling it. In this case, `L` eventually becomes `[]` and will no longer match `[_|L]`. This is important because, otherwise, you will get an infinite recursion.